# I'm getting LNK2019 errors using SDL 2.0.1 in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, compiler-errors, sdl, sdl-2

Here are the error codes and [here](http://pastebin.com/UjQP5bTA)
**[VectorEngine.h]**

```
#ifndef _CAPP_H_
#define _CAPP_H_
#include  <SDL.h>

class VectorEngine
{
    private:

        bool        running;
        SDL_Window* Surf_Display;

    public:
        VectorEngine();
        void onExecute();
        bool OnInit();
        void OnEvent(SDL_Event* Event);
        void OnTick();
        void OnRender();
        void OnCLeanup();
};
#endif
```

**[Main.cpp]**

```
#include"VectorEngine.h"
#include <Windows.h>

const int TICKS_PER_SECOND = 25;
const int SKIP_TICKS = 1000 / TICKS_PER_SECOND;
const int MAX_RENDERSKIPS = 5;

VectorEngine::VectorEngine()
{
    Surf_Display = NULL;
    running = true;
    OnInit();
    onExecute();
}

void VectorEngine::onExecute()
{
    SDL_Event Event;
    DWORD next_game_tick = GetTickCount();
    while (running)
    {
        int skippedRenders = 0;
        while (GetTickCount()> next_game_tick && skippedRenders < MAX_RENDERSKIPS)
        {
            OnTick();
            next_game_tick += SKIP_TICKS;
            skippedRenders++;
        }
        OnRender();
    }
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    VectorEngine  *vecEngine = new VectorEngine();
    return 0;
}
```

**[Oninit.cpp]**

```
#include "VectorEngine.h"

bool VectorEngine::OnInit()
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    Surf_Display = SDL_CreateWindow("My Game Window",
                                    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                                    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                                    640, 480,
                                    SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN| SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    return true;
}
```

**[OnCLeanup.cpp]**

```
#include"VectorEngine.h"

void VectorEngine::OnCLeanup()
{
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

This is the link to all the code an [here]([image: http://imgur.com/a/5PwDR]).

[image]

[image]

This is the link to all the linker settings:

```
Error    5    error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup    C:\Users\XSoloDoloX\Desktop\VecEng\GameForReal\GameForReal\MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj)    GameForReal

Error    2    error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_Quit referenced in function "public: void __thiscall VectorEngine::OnCLeanup(void)" (?OnCLeanup@VectorEngine@@QAEXXZ)    C:\Users\XSoloDoloX\Desktop\VecEng\GameForReal\GameForReal\OnCleanup.obj    GameForReal

Error    4    error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_Init referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall VectorEngine::OnInit(void)" (?OnInit@VectorEngine@@QAE_NXZ)    C:\Users\XSoloDoloX\Desktop\VecEng\GameForReal\GameForReal\OnInit.obj    GameForReal

Error    3    error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_CreateWindow referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall VectorEngine::OnInit(void)" (?OnInit@VectorEngine@@QAE_NXZ)    C:\Users\XSoloDoloX\Desktop\VecEng\GameForReal\GameForReal\OnInit.obj    GameForReal

Error    6    error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals    C:\Users\XSoloDoloX\Desktop\VecEng\GameForReal\Debug\GameForReal.exe    1    1    GameForReal
```

Comment: [Hope this will help you](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2a7b43de-60ed-4274-8a67-349a2a34da7a/faq-28-why-would-one-get-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol?forum=vcgeneral)

Comment: @Ankit B it really didn't help I have all the libraries referenced and  its still not working i even took screens of me adding them http://imgur.com/a/5PwDR i don't understand what is wrong.

Comment: Im not entirely sure what you mean by that. Are you refering to me using SDL

Comment: no i mean SDK are u using Visual studio or Turbo c for programming

Comment: Oh Im pretty sure its reffered to as an IDE or at least thats what I was taught it was. Its vc++ 2013

Comment: please try '#include<stdafx.h>' in all the .h files hope this will help you

Comment: You are missing SDL.lib from the linker input.

Comment: @cup I have that http://imgur.com/a/5PwDR

Comment: Try to use the x86 libs instead of x64 libs

Answer (score 2):

Ok So I figured it out for some reason using the x64 libraries was causing the errors so using x86 fixed the problems!